# OSX Cocoa embed opengl view inside webview

Tags: macos, cocoa, opengl

I am trying to build an MacOS app which create an OpenGL view  and embed it to webview as it's element (using OpenGL instead of WebGL). The main goal is to use the web (html/javascript) as UI and draw the result with OpenGL view. (besides, the OpenGL view will also handle the user input)

The issue is the overlay between the webview and OpenGL view. If OpenGL view on top of webview, the webview UI (like: dropdown box) possible cut by the OpenGL view. The webview on top of OpenGL view, all of the webview view will block the OpenGL view.

Is there any solution to solve this? (OpenGL and Webview)

Comment: Can't you just add a web view and an OpenGL view vertically stacked, instead of trying to embed one inside the other? A screenshot would make it easier to response to this.

Comment: issue here: [OpenGL view cut the web view dropdown button](http://postimage.org/image/tyd416uvd/)

Comment: Maybe instead of a web view, you could use some custom NSViews and an NSPopupButton? That should work well, making the popup display atop the OpenGL view when it's expanded. One way or another, I think that popover needs to be its own view.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion and it's a good idea. But we hope to use the web(html/javascript) as UI and OpenGL render the result (for the performance).

Comment: Maybe you can design a UI without a popover, then, or make sure the popover fits inside the web view instead of pouring over the edge.

Answer (score 1):

WebKit has an interesting functionality where you can associate webviews with certain MIME types to your own custom NSView classes.

In your HTML webview, you can put an iframe which has a custom mimetype (e.g. "application/my-custom-view").

After that, from your native app, you can call:

```
[WebView registerViewClass:[MyCustomView class] representationClass:[MyCustomRepresentation class] forMIMEType:@"application/my-custom-view"];
```

See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Webkit/Classes/WebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/WebView/registerViewClass:representationClass:forMIMEType:

MyCustomRepresentation can be pretty lightweight, my Representation class doesn't do anything, it just defines stub delegate functions.

Comment: thanks for the useful information. We start porting our library to NPAPI (later for PPAPI) and using the web browser (drawing with CALAYER) as the app (instead of native osx app).