# Inject NSView in WebView

Tags: macos, cocoa, webview

I am working on `Cocoa` application in `Xcode 6.1.1` on `OSX 10.10.2`

How do I inject the NSView at the top of web page so that the NSView looks like an integral part of the html page.
I tried insert the NSView by recursively searching for WebClipView and tried to add a testSubView, but it failed.

Following are the sample recursive logs of my webview.

```
]  WebFrameView
]   WebDynamicScrollBarsView
]    WebClipView
]     WebHTMLView
]      WebLayerHostingFlippedView
]      WebFrameView
]       WebDynamicScrollBarsView
]        WebClipView
]         WebHTMLView
]      WebFrameView
]       WebDynamicScrollBarsView
]        WebClipView
]         WebHTMLView
]      WebFrameView
]       WebDynamicScrollBarsView
]        WebClipView
]         WebHTMLView
]      WebHostedNetscapePluginView
]    NSScroller
```

I also tried inserting a `<div></div>` in dom but the outcome is not consistent.

Answer (score 1):

You should not try to modify the WebView view hierarchy directly. You are very likely to either step onto WebKit's toes, or have your own toes crushed.

You might want to look into this:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/WebView/registerViewClass:representationClass:forMIMEType:

The method `+ (void)registerViewClass:(Class)viewClass representationClass:(Class)representationClass forMIMEType:(NSString *)MIMEType` should allow you to use a custom view as part of your web page. You will need to have it as part of the DOM, though.

Related question: [OSX Cocoa embed opengl view inside webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14932775/osx-cocoa-embed-opengl-view-inside-webview/19579053)